# Why is my popToRootViewControllerAnimated not getting called?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have even tried implementing a delay right before the call to popToRootViewControllerAnimated however that does no good either. It just does not get called.

```
-(IBAction) btnSignOut{

    [[self tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0];

    [[self navigationController]popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];//DOES NOT GET CALLED




    Overview *overviewController = [[Overview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overview" bundle:nil];

    //Lets place OverView in navController
    UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:overviewController];



//  [[self navigationController] popToViewController:ComposeViewController animated:YES];

    //Now lets display it 
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [navController release];
    [overviewController release];


}
```

Comment: Is that view controller getting pushed initially?

Comment: What is the name of the base class of `-(IBAction) btnSignOut` ?

Comment: UIViewController...which is placed in a UINavigation root view controller

Comment: No it is not. However the [[self tabBarController]setSelectedIndex:0];
gets me back to that UINavigationController and I am trying to do a popToRootViewControllerAnimated from there

Comment: You need to tell how you pushed the view controller onto nav controller in first place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the [self navigationController] does not contain any view to pop